# Can you trigger an automatic memory dump on an OOM exception in .NET Core on Kubernetes?

Tags: memory, kubernetes, .net-core, containers, out-of-memory

I'm trying to find a way to trigger a memory dump when a container experiences an OOM exception. The problem is that when this happens, the container is restarted so we're unable to get a valid dump. I saw a [similar article outlining how to do it in Java](https://danlebrero.com/2018/11/20/how-to-do-java-jvm-heapdump-in-kubernetes/), but I'm not sure if/how this can be translated to .NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to do this.

For both ways to work, .Net Core needs to support a flag which tells it to dump on crash and a flag to pass it the path of where to dump.

1. Have a sidecar with shared storage on the microservice pod. In the sidecar, have a script that monitors the storage and copies the files dumped there to a location like a s3. I guess this is the one mentioned in the Java link
2. Have a storage common storage attached to all the pods of a Microservice, something like a NFS, in amazon's case, EFS. Use that efs in your deployment and make the .Net dump to that storage. Then it's only a matter to getting the dump out which you can do via a debug pod or a jumphost attached to the EFS

Comment: Thanks for the response - I guess there is more of a question around the "dump on crash" portion of this. I haven't had much luck finding a way to trigger that in .NET Core - are you aware of any ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a shared storage, and set the according Environment variables to tell .net core write dump to the shared storage when its process crashes.

More details are in this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dumps#collect-dumps-on-crash.